# What are the uses for the trophy items in Seiklus?

Tags: seiklus

I have finished Seiklus, and it was great, but I'm still wondering if I used everything to its fullest abilities.

There is a trophy stand of sorts on the map screen which holds a number of interesting items:

[image: Interesting trophy stand]

At first I thought they were just, well, trophies. Only shiny things to look at. Later on I realized that one of them actually has a purpose.

So now I'm wondering if the other trophies have a purpose. I didn't really notice anything else special happening while I was playing the game, but I would think that if one has an ability the others must.

**So what are the functions of these items?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know their names (if they even have official names), so I made some up. At least five of the seven "medallions" have a function.

There is an ["official" walkthrough](http://autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/publicity/seiklus_walkthrough_by_andrewfm.txt) that also describes these items, and it comes to the same conclusions about the powers of each item. I've added (in parentheses) the names that the walkthrough's author gives each item.

From the left to right:

**Bird (Invisible Platform) medallion** - *Looks like flying bird*. Gives you the ability to detect where invisible platforms (you'll see blinking blocks) are located.

**Plant (Claw) medallion** - *Looks like those (hidden) plants that eat you*. Gives you the ability to see (you'll see a slight sparkle) those (pesky) plants, so that you can avoid being eaten.

**Fish (same) medallion** - *Looks like a crescent-shaped fish with spikes*. Makes one of the fish in the giant lake follow you.

**(??) medallion** - *Looks like a cave or a shell*. I have no clue what this does.

**(???) medallion** - *Looks like a sailboat or something*. I have no clue what this does, either.

**Snake (White) medallion** *Looks like a snake in the upside down U shape*. Lets you see where the hidden white orbs (white flashing dots) are from the map screen.

**Star (same) medallion** - *Looks like a star*. Gives you the power of the "W" (key)!

Comment: Wow, this explains a _lot_. I remember many of these effects but didn't take much notice of them or when they started occurring. You have connected the dots for me, thanks. P.S.- It appears that "medallion" is the official unofficial name for these items, as that is what they seem to be called in the ["official" walkthrough](http://autofish.net/clysm/art/video_games/seiklus/publicity/seiklus_walkthrough_by_andrewfm.txt). I'll appended this reference to your answer. It looks like you'll even pick up a bounty. :)